# create dynamic table for comparing data column wise

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I would like to create table result in dynamic format like
data is coming from asp.net api and can be available in object or json format
like

```html
`
    [{"title":'Header1', {"prop1":"data1"}.....},
{"title":"Header2", {"prop1":"data1"}.....}
]
`
```

|-------------------------------------------------------|

```
      | Header1 | Header2   |............
```

|-------------------------------------------------------|

| prop1   |  data1  | data2   |

|-------------------------------------------------------|

|prop2    |  data12| data22 |

--------------------------------------------------------|

Comment: Please take some time to read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and the [Stack Overflow question checklist by Jon Skeet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist)

Answer (score 0):

Please reference some jquery plugins like datatables, they have great functionality and can be molded to do just about anything you want.

https://datatables.net/